# How we can ForEach 12,000 excel sheet rows inside 3 separate ForEach inside our Power Automate Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

We have a workflow which read an excel sheet which contain 12,000 rows >> then Foreach those rows, as follow:

[image]

Now the issue is that the first action will read all the 12,000 rows >> but the Foreach can handle only the first 5000 rows.

So is there a way to force the flow to have 3 ForEachs? first one will process the rows from 1 to 5000 >> second will process the rows from 5001 to 10,000 >> last one will process the rows from 10,001 to the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `skip(...)` and `take(...)` functions. `skip(...)` will skip a number of items from the beginning of an array, e.g. to skip 5000 items:

```
skip([array_of_items],5000)
```

`take(...)` will take a number of items from the beginning of an array, e.g. to take first 5000 items from an array:

```
take([array_of_items],5000)
```

If you combine them together, you can take items 5001 - 10000 from an array:

```
take(skip([array],5000),5000)
```

So you can create three parallel branches in your flow:

- Branch one: `take([array_of_items],5000)`
- Branch two: `take(skip([array],5000),5000)`
- Branch three: `take(skip([array],10000),5000)`

Then, inside each branch, you can have a separate foreach iterator.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so you mean the Skip and take inside the Action options?

Comment: You can do it inside your Apply for each action, in the Select an option from previous steps field like so: `take(skip([List_rows_output_goes_here],10000),5000)`